# A prime number topology

Tags: general-topology

For a prime number $p$, let $S_p = \{ n \in \Bbb N : n \text{ is a multiple of }p\}$.

(a) Show that $\mathcal{S} := \{S_p : p \text{ is prime}\} \cup \{\{1\}\}$ is a subbasis on $\Bbb N$.

**(b)** Describe the open sets in the topology generated by $\mathcal{S}$ (qualitatively).

**(a)** Any positive number greater than one is a composite number or a prime number.  As such if the number is prime then it is clearly part of the set.  If it’s a composite number then it’s in the form of $p_1 \cdot p_2\cdot \ldots \cdot p_n$ so we can select any one of the prime numbers, say $p_m$ and then we multiply it by the product of all the other prime numbers ie, $x=p_1\cdot p_2 \cdot \dots \cdot p_n$ (with exception of $p_m$) so $x$, an element of $\Bbb N$, is the multiple of a prime number.  Since {1} is also an element of S,  the set $\mathcal{S}$ covers $\Bbb N$.

**(b)** Any set in $S$ is an arithmetic sequence starting from a particular prime number and then goes up by the prime number and the set also has the element 1.  So the intersection of a finite number of elements of S are arithmetic sequences themselves plus the element 1. So the union of these sets are open sets and are unions of arithmetic sequences plus the element 1.

Not sure if my answers are correct, on the right track or neither.  Can someone please advise.

Comment: Note that $\{1\}$ is one of the sub-basic open sets, rather than $1$ being an element of  each $S_p$. This is relevant for  a) since $1$ has no prime divisor.

Comment: Is $0 \in \Bbb N$?

Comment: not 100% percent sure but assuming N is Z+

Comment: is one of the sets of S not {1,2,4,6,8...}?  Is the set instead {2,4,6,8...} U {1} and if its the latter and not the former are the two not the same

Comment: No, $\{2,4,6,8\}$ is one set and $\{1\}$ is another. Their union *is* open, but not in $\mathcal{S}$.

Comment: ok, thank you   i think it makes sense to me now.  {1} is an open set in the topology generated since its the intersection and union of itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the $\{1\}$ to cover $\Bbb N$ as it has no prime divisor. All $n \neq 1$ have a prime divisor $p$ and then by definition $n \in S_p$. That proves a).

As $S_p \cap S_q$ is the set of all multiples of $pq$, the finite intersections of the subbasic elements are multiples of integers $n$ that are of the form $p_1p_2\ldots p_n$ where the $p_i$ are different primes (I'll call them "monoprime integers"). $1$ is an isolated point, and if $0 \in \Bbb N$, it is a dense point (probably not intended). So $O$ is open iff $O \setminus \{1\}$ is a union of $S_n$ with $n$ "monoprime".

Comment: so for part (a) do i just add that {1}is an element of S and then the answer would be complete?  Or would it still be incorrect

Comment: @AlexM. The $\{1\}$ is important and should be mentioned.

Comment: Is {1} not an element of O?

Comment: @AlexM. It is an open set and a member of $\mathcal{S}$.